# Multiple window onload functions with only Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an external JS file that adds a window.onload function to the page.

The basic premise is that it loads up a popup window on your website whenever the user clicks on certain link class. It's written in PHP / JS so assume that the function works by itself.

Inside this JS file has the following code.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("vyper-triggers");
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    anchor.onclick = function() {
      if (isMobile.any()) {
        window.open("$url");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("clickonthis").click();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is when my user wants to add 2 different popup windows, the window.onload function doesn't stack. Also because this is an embedded javascript that my user adds himself, there is no way for me to put both functions inside one big window.onload function.

My user might put one JS file in one area of their site, and another JS file in another area, if that makes sense.

So how do I make it so that the window.onload function will stack no matter the placing of these external JS files on the page and considering that each function must be kept separate?

Comment: Use proper `window.addEventListener("load", …)`: http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: I heard this doesn't work with IE, is that true?

Comment: Yes. If you mean ancient Internet Explorers that died out long ago.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than setting `window.onload`, you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Listeners added this way will stack automatically.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('First listener');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Second listener');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Third listener');
});
```

If you have to support versions of IE before IE9, [there's a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) which will make this work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have multiple files and u want to check something `onload`.

Let's implement a basic function to add other functions and run all of them when the event `onload` is triggered.

So, first we check if `windows.onload` has a `function` object if not add our `function`. If is contains a `function` object merge it with our `function` like this:

```js
function addLoadEvent(callback) {
    const previous = window.onload
    if (typeof previous === 'function') {
        window.onload = (e) => {
            if (previous) previous(e)
            
            callback(e)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This is an example how to use it:

```js
 
function addLoadEvent(callback) {
    const previous = window.onload
    if (typeof previous === 'function') {
        window.onload = (e) => {
            if (previous) previous(e)

            callback(e)
        }
    } else {
        window.onload = callback
    }
}

function func1() { 
  console.log('This is the first.') 
}
 
function func2() { 
  console.log('This is the second.')
}
 
addLoadEvent(func1); 
addLoadEvent(func2); 
addLoadEvent(() => { 
  console.log('This is the third.')
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#EFDF95'
})
```